# Compress/Minify JSON in AJAX requests/responses

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, compression, minify

I was checking out some of the code on Facebook, specifically the headers of the AJAX requests/responses and noticed that they seem to be compress/minified just like one would do with CSS or JavaScript.

This would turn

```
{ id: 1000, username: "testing" }
```

Turns into this:

```
{a:1000,b:"testing"}
```

Is this possible with ASP.NET MVC in any way? I'd like to explore this idea and wondered if there was some special model binding technique that could be used?

Comment: What library are you using to encode? JSON.NET or the defaul `Json(...)` `ViewResult`?

Comment: @BradChristie - Just default, but I'd switch if there is a different way... I assume the client would have to somehow serialize the JSON?

Comment: The client doesn't care; you're two examples are identical to a client, just whitespace is included in one of them. You could add a customer `ActionFilter` which would strip that out, or use a "tighter" JSON encoder.

Comment: I'm not sure your correct. I was meaning 'a' would bind to "id" and 'b' to "username" on the server side...

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Sorry, late night of coding has the eyes bugging out. Yes, you would need to have some form of client association or mapping to know that `id` maps to `a`, and `username`->`b`. If you're using knockoutjs that's easy enough to do with the mapping tools.

Comment: its called an array, (json can mix types in an array) seemed odd at first coming from C, but nice once you get used to it ... that and having associative arrays like awk make them pretty powerful

Comment: The extra complexity this would introduce is really not worth it unless you've proved that the bottleneck in your application is network transfer of JSON.

Comment: @MichaelMior - yes I agree but I thought maybe there was something out there already...

Comment: @Ryan Even if there is, I personally would avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: It's going to make debugging more complicated. Anywhere you might log your JSON, you'll have one extra layer of abstraction. And it's also one other potential source of bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **Custom Binding** is the way to go.
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) is a good brief explanation.

--- more detail ---
you can intercept binding `json` data shipped by `QueryString` and convert received json into desired model.